# Tag Question on No One Was

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

Is

```
No one was asked to play, were they?
```

correct or should it be something different?

Comment: That is what I would say.

Comment: @ColinFine Agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Make my comment an answer):

That is what I would say.